# select, insert query in mariadb using python

Tags: python, mariadb

I want to move some data between two databases. So i make the following query, aproximately:
insert into database.table select * from anotherdatabase.table.

But when doing cursor.execute(¨¨¨query¨¨¨) i get syntax error

Comment: Please show your exact code and the exact error message. Do you really have `"""query"""` in your code? In that case you try to execute the word "query" as an SQL command.

Comment: Have you tried the query directly into the database before implementing it? as the prior comment says we need to see the code to have a better understanding, you may be having a typo and runing an string that says query instead of the actual query

Comment: for example: CURSOR cursor.execute(INSERT INTO `db1`.table1 (
  xxx
, xxx
, xxxx)
(
SELECT
  xxx
, xxx
, xxx
FROM db2.table
INNER JOIN `db2`.atribute 
GROUP BY
  fecha
, xxx
, xxx)) and the error is You have an error in your sql syntax....

Comment: yes, running the query directly in sql works fine